# SubMenu getItem don't work

Tags: android, menu, submenu

I have created a Menu with subMenu and I try to set an event on the each last event.

It worked well excepted for the last itération of submenu(each subMenu can have a submenu or not, it's random).

I've add Sys.out to show itemId and ItemTitle for each submenu iteration, it worked all  the submenu exepted the last iteration (fourth subMenu)

```
public class Tab3 extends Activity {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuBase=MenuTest.menuBase;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menu1=MenuTest.menu1;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menu2=MenuTest.menu2;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menu3=MenuTest.menu3;
    Document doc3=MenuTest.doc3;
    ArrayList<Integer> idFin;

    static final String KEY_CATEGORY_2="category_2";
    static final String KEY_NAME_3="name_3";
    static final String KEY_CATEGORY_4="category_4";
    static final String KEY_NAME_5="name_5";
    static final String KEY_CATEGORY_6="category_6";
    static final String KEY_NAME_7="name_7";
    static final String KEY_CATEGORY_8="category_8";
    static final String KEY_NAME_9="name_9";
    static final String KEY_ID_3="id_3";
    static final String KEY_ID_5="id_5";
    static final String KEY_ID_7="id_7";
    static final String KEY_ID_9="id_9";

    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;


    Button categorie;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(Tab3.this);

        //viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(Tab3.this, R.layout.splash_screen, null));


        setContentView(R.layout.onglet3);
        categorie=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);               
        categorie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openOptionsMenu();
            }

        });


    }

    //Méthode qui se déclenchera lorsque vous appuierez sur le bouton menu du téléphone
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);

        NodeList nodes0 = doc3.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY_2);
        NodeList nodes1 = doc3.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY_4);
        NodeList nodes2 = doc3.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY_6);
        int sum0=0;
        int sum1=0;
        int sum2=0;
        idFin=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<menuBase.size();i++){
            SubMenu x0=menu.addSubMenu(0, Integer.parseInt(menuBase.get(i).get(KEY_ID_3).toString()), 0,changeToRegularForm(menuBase.get(i).get(KEY_NAME_3).toString()));
                int count0 = ((Element)(nodes0.item(i))).getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY_4).getLength();
                if(count0==0){
                    idFin.add(Integer.parseInt(menuBase.get(i).get(KEY_ID_3).toString()));
                }else{ 
                    for(int y0=sum0;y0<sum0+count0;y0++){

                        SubMenu x1=x0.addSubMenu(1, Integer.parseInt(menu1.get(y0).get(KEY_ID_5).toString()), 0,changeToRegularForm(menu1.get(y0).get(KEY_NAME_5).toString()));
                        int count1 = ((Element)(nodes1.item(y0))).getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY_6).getLength();

                        if(count1==0){
                            idFin.add(Integer.parseInt(menu1.get(y0).get(KEY_ID_5).toString()));
                        }else{
                            for(int y1=sum1;y1<sum1+count1;y1++){
                                SubMenu x2=x1.addSubMenu(2, Integer.parseInt(menu2.get(y1).get(KEY_ID_7).toString()), 0, changeToRegularForm(menu2.get(y1).get(KEY_NAME_7).toString()));
                                int count2 = ((Element)(nodes2.item(y1))).getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY_8).getLength();
                                if(count2==0){
                                    idFin.add(Integer.parseInt(menu2.get(y1).get(KEY_ID_7).toString()));
                                }
                                else{
                                    for(int y2=sum2;y2<sum2+count2;y2++){

                                        idFin.add(Integer.parseInt(menu3.get(y2).get(KEY_ID_9).toString()));
                                        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(menu3.get(y2).get(KEY_ID_9).toString()));
                                        x2.addSubMenu(3, Integer.parseInt(menu3.get(y2).get(KEY_ID_9).toString()), 0,changeToRegularForm(menu3.get(y2).get(KEY_NAME_9).toString()));


                                    }
                                }
                                sum2+=count2;
                            }
                        }

                        sum1+=count1;
                    }
               }
               sum0+=count0;
        }






        return true;
     }

       //Méthode qui se déclenchera au clic sur un item
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         //On regarde quel item a été cliqué grâce à son id et on déclenche une action

            System.out.println(item.getItemId());
            System.out.println(item.getTitle());


          if(idFin.contains(item.getItemId())){
            Intent shopEntry= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShopLayout.class);

            shopEntry.putExtra("idProduct", ""+item.getItemId());
            System.out.println(item.getItemId());

            startActivity(shopEntry);
         }
         return false;}


    public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
      Node child = e.getFirstChild();
      if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
      }
      return "";
    }

    private String changeToRegularForm(String s){
        if(s.contains("Ã©")){
            s=s.replace("Ã©", "é");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã¢")){
            s=s.replace("Ã¢", "â");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã¨")){
            s=s.replace("Ã¨", "è");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ãª")){
            s=s.replace("Ãª", "ê");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã«")){
            s=s.replace("Ã«", "ë");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã®")){
            s=s.replace("Ã®", "î");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã¯")){
            s=s.replace("Ã¯", "ï");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã´")){
            s=s.replace("Ã´", "ô");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã¶")){
            s=s.replace("Ã¶", "ö");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã¹")){
            s=s.replace("Ã¹", "ù");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã»")){
            s=s.replace("Ã»", "û");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã¼")){
            s=s.replace("Ã¼", "ü");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã§")){
            s=s.replace("Ã§", "ç");
        }

        if(s.contains("Å")){
            s=s.replace("Å", "œ");
        }

        if(s.contains("â¬")){
            s=s.replace("â¬", "€");
        }

        if(s.contains("Ã")){
            s=s.replace("Ã", "à");
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Logcat:

```
05-15 09:03:37.268: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 295 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:03:37.749: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:03:47.069: I/System.out(794): 2
05-15 09:03:47.069: I/System.out(794): Cosmétiques
05-15 09:03:47.488: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:03:48.829: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 338 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:03:58.331: I/System.out(794): 180
05-15 09:03:58.399: I/System.out(794): Maquillage 
05-15 09:03:58.769: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 146 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:04:00.269: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 385 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:04:03.291: I/System.out(794): 1024
05-15 09:04:03.330: I/System.out(794): yeux
05-15 09:04:03.639: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:04:04.669: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 260 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:04:05.849: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 09:04:06.439: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: What happens when you get to the fourth sub menu? Does an exception get thrown? If so please post stack trace.

Comment: Nothing happens, the menu close and that's all (any trace in logcat);

Comment: So you are able to see the fourth level sub menu item on the screen, but when you click on it nothing happens?

Comment: Yeah, I see the fourth submenu, but when I click on is just close and nothing happens in the logcat(for the other submenu I can see id and title appear with this two line System.out.println(item.getItemId()); System.out.println(item.getTitle());) I'll gona tried on real device, it can be emulateur fail but i don't think.

Comment: don't work on a real device too

Comment: I've adding a logcat example. After clicking on "yeux" i've a sub menu who appear with two choices, when i click on each one nothing happens on the logcat but submenu closed.

Comment: if i adding to the second submenu until to the third, the item work good (expected he wa'snt on his real position)

Comment: it's just like the fourth submenu wasn't affect onOptionsItemSelected() method ><